# Why is there a big margin in my scrollview when it's all set to 0

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have scrollview with a stackview with all my contents. I set all my margins to 8px but for some reason, there is a big space to the right. Even if I change the margin to 0px.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is it maybe better to make a tableview and make a cell out of my stackview? Seems very unnecessary to do this. But I cant figure this out.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to suggest anything without knowing every constraint you are using for the whole viewController.

Comment: You should constrain your stack view top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide**, then constrain the stack view's Width to the scroll view's **Frame Layout Guide**. Based on the image you have shown, it appears your stack view Width is being determined by the width of its arranged subviews.

Comment: @creeperspeak the stack view has top,bottom,leading and trailing as seen on the image. the scrollview has also top,bottom,leading and trailing all set to 0

Comment: @DonMag it appears that way, but there are no constraints in the stackview.

Comment: @DanielMedinaSada - *"there are no constraints in the stackview"* ... OK, then that's the problem.

Comment: @DanielMedinaSada - I'm assuming you have set width constraints on your text fields? Do you want to keep the widths, and horizontally center the "form stack view" in the scroll view, like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1vqm.png

Answer (score 0):

When you define constraints inside a `scrollview`, the content doesn’t bind to the scrollview but to the content insets (*margins*). With this you can install content that is wider than the `scrollview` and be able to scroll horizontally.

What that means is the content of your scrollview can’t deduce its width just by sticking constraints to the sides, you have to explicitly set a width constraint on a child view.

In your example, it will use the smallest width it can, which looks to be the width of your three checkboxes.

To fix that, add a width constraint to any child view, like your first text field, or better, on your text edit because it takes the whole width.

In addition to this, you should add a `CenterHorizontally` constraint on your text edit too and make your left constraint on "Equal or Greater" or else your content will be aligned to the left.

---

Here is the [official documentation on ScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1) to see this in more detail.

Answer (score -2):

The content inside the scrollView must be the width of the device. The scrollView will not adjust to that width by itself. First try to set "equal widths" constraint of the scroll view to the view controller. If that doesn't work, keep reading.

For this StoryBoard, what you must do is put a UIView inside the scrollView.

The scrollView must be equal widths and equal heights of the viewController. Then the UIView must be equal widths of the scrollView, and then set its top and bottom anchor to the top and bottom anchor of the scrollview.
Copy all your subviews into this UIView.